# Capybara-Finding an arbitrery item on a html page

Tags: html, testing, capybara

I'm trying to automate some tests on an html page which has a code like this:

```
<br>
<strong>DOCUMENTS</strong>
<br>
No file found.
<br>
<br>
<strong>OUTGOING-DOCUMENTS</strong>
<br>
<table>
<br>
```

When you list all documents in a category, it generates a table if any file is present, and writes "No file found" if there is none.

My question is: How can I access these tables generically ? One thing that I thought of is to access them through line breaks. Since there are fixed numbers of breaks, if I check between break 5 and break 6 , I'd find a table or a "No file found" message.

Any suggestions for doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : here is a solution specific to my problem. Solution elements may be changed for customizing it.
    find(("strong:contains('#{options[i]}') + br + table"))
This returns en element if there is a table in that location. You have to handle an exception if the table isn't there

```
    begin
      el = find(("strong:contains('#{options[i]}') + br + table"))   
      files = el.all('tr')
      p "#{files.length} files for #{options[i]}"
    rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
      p "No report for #{options[i]}"
    end
```